# How Can I add underline option & Alignment option in toolbar of CKEditor5 in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, text-alignment, underline

How can I add options as Text Alignment & Underline in CKEditor in reactjs, I tried but did not get success.
Please help me

```
text-editor.js

import React from 'react'
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const TextEditor = ({handleChildClick}) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <CKEditor
                editor={ ClassicEditor }
                onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                    const data = editor.getData();
                    handleChildClick(data)
                } }
            />
            <style>
                {`
                .ck-content { height: 150px; }
                `}
            </style>
        </div>
    );
}; 
export default TextEditor
```

```
Parent.js

<TextEditor handleChildClick={getDataFromTextEditor} />
```

[image: for reference]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the ClassicEditor removes some buttons like the "Underline, Subscript, Superscript". You will need to use a Customized version of the editor and not the Classic version.

I've come in contact with CKEditor team. They have sent me to their online builder : 
**https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/**

I've tried it and it looks simple enough to use. There are a lot of options so you'll need to go through it.

Basically, pick your Editor type, add plugins, choose your language, build and use the build.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for this In your preferred Language?

Answer (score 2):

I see the question is already answered, but I thought I could add how I solved this.

While installing the ckeditor for react I used

```dos
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document
```

in place of the example given in the docs

```dos
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

and then I followed the method of creating a decoupled editor as shown in the docs

```react
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';

class App extends Component {
    editor = null;

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2>CKEditor 5 using a custom build - decoupled editor</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    onReady={ editor => {
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                        editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
                            editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
                            editor.ui.getEditableElement()
                        );

                        this.editor = editor;
                    } }
                    onError={ ( { willEditorRestart } ) => {

                        // This is why you need to remove the older toolbar.
                        if ( willEditorRestart ) {
                            this.editor.ui.view.toolbar.element.remove();
                        }
                    } }
                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => console.log( { event, editor } ) }
                    editor={ DecoupledEditor }
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5's decoupled editor!</p>"
                    config={ /* the editor configuration */ }
                />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for Angular, would be helpful if anyone looking for this.

Reference:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/156
1)

> npm install --save ckeditor5-build-classic-plus

2. include in hmtl

> <ckeditor (ready)="editorsReady($event)" [editor]="Editor" data="test"
> [config]="optionsNews">

3. include in ts file where you are using the editor(eg any editor compoenent)

> import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-build-classic-plus';

```
public editorsReady(editor) {
         editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
         editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
       editor.ui.getEditableElement() );
       }
```